# issues with raw update query in django

Tags: django, django-views, sql-update

I am using raw update query in my project, I have to update a column with some value which is dynamic and comes from a function and it is stored in a variable.But when i run the following update query i am getting an error:

```
UPDATE shop_cartitem SET total_price =update_amt WHERE cart_id = %s", [cart_abj.id]
```

my error **1054, "Unknown column 'update_amt' in 'field list'")**

But i run with a static value `UPDATE shop_cartitem SET total_price =100 WHERE cart_id = %s", [cart_abj.id]`   then it execute correctly.

So please tell me ow i can run this update query with a dynamic variable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
"UPDATE shop_cartitem SET total_price = %s WHERE cart_id = %s" % (update_amt, cart_abj.id)
```